# Running my own job on Giraph

Tags: giraph

So, I've successfully executed the SimpleShortestPathComputation on my computer via the script shown here:

```
#VARIABLES
user_dir=/user/hduser
jar=giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.1.0-for-hadoop-2.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
runner=org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner
computation=org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation
informat=org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat
outformat=org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat

#DELETE PREVIOUS
bin/hdfs dfs -rm -r $user_dir/output/shortestpaths

#GIRAPH JOB
bin/hadoop jar $GIRAPH_HOME/$jar $runner -Dgiraph.yarn.task.heap.mb=3000 $computation -vif $informat -vip $user_dir/input/tiny_graph.txt -vof $outformat -op $user_dir/output/shortestpaths -w 1
```

Now the problem is, I'm trying to run my own job. It's actually a direct copy-paste from the SimpleShortestPathComputation class, only changed the package name and class name. Trying to run it with -libjars. Here's the full script:

```
#VARIABLES
user_dir=/user/hduser
jar=giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.1.0-for-hadoop-2.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
runner=org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner
computation=org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation
informat=org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat
outformat=org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat
libjars=/usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/lib/giraphtrials.jar,$GIRAPH_HOME/giraph-core.jar

#Setup class paths
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/lib/giraphtrials.jar:$GIRAPH_HOME/$jar:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH

#DELETE PREVIOUS
bin/hdfs dfs -rm -r $user_dir/output/shortestpaths

#GIRAPH JOB
bin/hadoop jar $GIRAPH_HOME/$jar $runner -libjars $libjars \
GiraphAlgs.GiraphPBFS -vif $informat -vip $user_dir/input/tiny_graph.txt \
-vof $outformat -op $user_dir/output/shortestpaths -w 1
```

As you can see, I've tried to use -libjars and HADOOP_CLASSPATH suggestion from [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084629/classnotfoundexception-running-giraphrunner-on-a-modified-simpleshortestpathsver) to make it work but unfortunately it still gives me a ClassNotFoundException. For better or worse, it doesn't throw it at me in the terminal anymore (it used to): [terminal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PStj5.png). As you can see, it only fails with a general container message now.

Unfortunately, it still gives me the Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in the logs: [log picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXoFa.png).
Using Hadoop 2.4.0 and Giraph 1.1.0.
I'm running out of ideas what might be wrong with my Giraph and starting to think if I should change careers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the jar which contains the class GiraphAlgs.GiraphPBFS in the hadoop classpath.

Also, verify that your classpath is correct set by running `$bin/hadoop classpath`.

Once in hadoop 2.7 setting HADOOP_CLASSPATH variable didn't work, I had to copy the jar in the hadoop share lib directory: `HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib`.

Comment: Using $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib actually worked! Previously I had tried $HADOOP_HOME/lib/share and just putting the jars on classpath but this one actually made some progress for me. Thanks a lot!